# After magento move to another server skin/css not working

Tags: magento

After migrating magento from one to another hosting with different domain, I'm getting one problem - http://vinylshop.lt/ don't loading skin/css..

Any solutions?

I found similar solution - http://blog.wayyi.com/incorrect-css-and-js-path-varwwwmagentoskin-after-moving-magento-to-new-server

but in table core_config_data where are no dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files and don't know how to add them

Comment: If those paths are missing, then the default value applies, and the default value is "no".

Comment: Sorry, don't understand, what need to do?

Comment: Some files from skin page using, logo/favicon..

Comment: Yes, the files are there. `http://vinylshop.lt/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css` - though if that has been modified it should be moved to a custom theme, as it will be overwritten in an upgrade.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your source indicates that merging is enabled. You can run the following sql to update your `core_config_data` table; backup first!

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 0 WHERE `path` = "dev/js/merge_files" OR `path` = "dev/css/merge_css_files";
```

You should see at least two rows affected. Remove everything from `var/cache/`.

Also, it looks like you need to move over your `.htaccess` file as well, as the value for `web/seo/use_rewrites` seems to be enabled. Depending on your version, you can grab the original file from the repo (version number points to latest stable patch level):

```
http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/.htaccess
```

Comment: As I said, where are no these rows dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files , because I'm getting error: Affected rows: 0 (Query took 0.0015 sec)

Comment: It appears you have a non-standard css and js merging solution in place. Perhaps Fooman Speedster? CSS and JS merges merge under `media` folder out of box.

Comment: I think that i don't have this extension. I can't check, because I can't click anything in admin, because and i there is no css - http://cl.ly/1T2z100K2s0b3Q0k2V1U

Comment: Check in app/code/community and app/code/local. For the former, anything other than Phoenix and Find is custom. For the latter, anything is custom.

Comment: Yes, Fooman Speedster folder is in app/code/community . Do you think that this one bugging css/js? How can I remove it?

Comment: I changed folder name, and now css/js working !!!! Nice, but any solution to make downloader work, because like i show, downloader getting Internal Server Error

Comment: Try removing the .htaccess from the /downloader/ folder.  Also check the permissions and owner for it.

Answer (score 0):

Change Permission Of Skin And Media  Containing **All Folder TO Give Permission 755** And **File TO 644**